# Identity Server 4 - authenticating a client that uses a part of the app in iframe

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

The problem i'm facing is quite unusual. We need to provide a page that an external client would be able to use in their own application through iframe. We use Identity Server 4 to secure all our APIs and I want to keep the communication secure. Is there a way to authenticate the company which will be using our page in an iframe (in a silent mode, i.e. without any pop-ups or login screens) and keep this communication secure? Should we use certificate auth? How the flow would look like in this case?

Comment: Are you using MVC or WepAPI? What's inside the iframe. Will it be a new application like Angular? Do you need user context?

Comment: Is iframe embedded in specific ip/domain/something you can physically cut off access? What Authentication flows are you using now?

Comment: The front-end is Angular-based application that connects to database via service layer (WebAPI). User context is not required. The iframe will be embedded into a specific domain. We're using openid now.